# How to show apps in salesforce1?

Tags: salesforce1-app, salesforce1-platform

How to show App in salesforce1?
For Example we have many apps which are being present on the right hand corner of Salesforce such as Sales,Marketing,Community etc. Than how can we show these apps in Salesforce1.
As we have requirement such as to show app which has only defined tabs to be visible in Salesforce1.
Any kind of help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can only show visualforce pages (enabled for Salesforce1 Mobile) and Lightning pages/components in Salesforce1. They both require that you've created a tab for them. Once you've done that, they'll appear in a Dialogue as shown in the screenshot below.

Salesforce1 mobile only supports single page applications. For that reason, the "applications" you speak of such as "Sales", "Marketing", etc cannot be added to the Salesforce1 menu.

[image: Salesforce1 Mobile Navigation Configuration]